# If $a> 1$ and $x > 0$, prove that $a^x > 1$ without the use of Calculus.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the study of exponential functions we notice that they are increasing or decreasing. In this way, we have the following question.

If $a> 1$ and $x > 0$, prove that $a^x > 1$ without the use of Calculus.

Comment: Hint : $a^x = e^{x \ln a}$

Comment: How are you defining $a^x$? You will need to use that definition.

Comment: you don't need presumptions about $a^x$ being increasing, just use the exponential form given by @krirkrirk

Comment: How do you even *define* $a^x$ (or $e^x$) without the use of calculus?

Comment: Nice question Bungo.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

Assume to the contrary that

$
a^x \leq 1
$

Since $x>0$ and $a>1$:

$
\left(a^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}} \leq (1)^{\frac{1}{x}} \hspace{5 mm} \Rightarrow a \leq 1
$

a contradiction.

Thus, $a^x>1$

Answer (score 1):

Let assume on contrary that $a^x\le 1\;$ Now dividing both sides by a, we get $a^{x-1}\le a^{-1}$ $\implies x-1\le -1 \implies x\le 0$ which is a contradiction. Hence $a^x\gt 1$

Comment: You should probably start by assuming that $a^x \leq 1$ what you have now is missing the "what if $a^x=1$ case

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.